# How to pass real visitor IP to proxified site using nginx proxy?

Tags: nginx, proxy

I am making a mirror version for a site that blocked in my country using nginx proxy feature.

The probelm is:

The blocked site have a security measure to check the IP that request tha video page and compare it with the IP that request the video that hosted on their CDN.

But nginx always send the server IP not the IP of the user that used my mirror site that make the video page request and the video link from CDN have deferent IPs.

My config is:

```
server {
resolver 8.8.8.8 ipv6=off;
listen 0.0.0.0:80; 
server_name mydomain.com;

location / {
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    proxy_pass https://targetsite.com/;
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $remote_addr;
    proxy_ssl_verify off;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
 }
}
```

How to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: You also will have to proxy the videos from the CDN. Instead, you should ask the site administrator if they will whitelist your proxy because of the country blocking.

Comment: The problem now is on the main proxied site, becuase my server leak my server IP.  The main proxied site add the IP to the video source including some extra hash to the video url source. But always this url contain my server IP not the visitor real IP. I try to change the proxy_pass to https://www.whatismyip.com to check if the user real IP forward, and yes the https://www.whatismyip.com read the real IP. So i think the video website that i need to proxy is some how now my server IP.

Comment: I made a test website using the above config and point the proxy server to https://ipleak.net to see how thing goes. if you go to this url https://hdo.ooo you can see that https://ipleak.net is proxied through my website and on the first the ipleak show your real IP , but if you go down you can see that the ipleak.net id detecting the main server IP and it is location.

Comment: When you are proxying the connection to somewhere, the TCP connection used to connect to the proxied server is the proxy's IP address. You cannot change this behaviour at all, because it is a fundamental principle of TCP/IP networking.